# Tomcat9 web access other than localhost failed

Tags: java, https, tomcat9, ofbiz

I am trying to evaluate ofbiz ( v17.2.03 ) just now. I can access it via https://127.0.0.1:8443/.../ from local machine (192.168.110.182) but not from other machines. The error message is like(from Chrome),

**org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandlerException: Domain
192.168.110.182 not accepted to prevent host header injection.**

No idea at all, and please if someone can help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set host-headers-allowed property in security.properties file. I'll make the error message more explicit!

Update: done with

https://github.com/apache/ofbiz-framework/commit/3c9fe5f91684de54570e6ec61575c11368a2ffd6/

https://github.com/apache/ofbiz-framework/commit/d0fceffadda57dbe6e87398c47b4a575bc33137d/